# How to get a global variable in python with the equivalent of what it is named in a string

Tags: python

So I have a few global variables, lets name them one, two, and three for simplicity purposes.

```
global One

global Two

global Three

One = 1

Two = 2

Three = 3
```

I then have a method inside of the function that returns the name of a global variable, but the name is in a string.

```
Dictionary.get(firstparameter)

y = Dictionary.get(firstparameter)
```

This returns the string "One"

What I need to do, is with the string "One", I need to know that I need to grab the global variable of One, and use it. But because it returns it via a string, I don't know how to do this.

I can't do an if statement because they are different types.

```
if One == y:
    print("success!")
elif Two == y:
    print("success!")
... etc
```

I figured out some way to do it but it is a terrible way I think and with so many edge cases. I tried using the keyword global() and filtering it out with equating the key of one of the global variables with the string of y

```
Dictionaryneeded = globals()

key = list(filter(lambda x: Dictionaryneeded[x] == y, Dictionaryneeded))[0]

print(key)
```

this should work but i think this is a terrible way to do it. anyone have any other ideas? Like what if the value of the key is something different?

I tried the global() keyword but I don't think its good.

Comment: Why aren't you just using an ordinary `dict` like `{'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3}`. Don't use the global (or any) namespace as if it were a `dict`.

Comment: Because these global variables are global and used across many different classes and functions

Comment: So? Make the dictionary global.

Comment: dang, i didnt think of that. @Barmar

Comment: *Any* time you care about the name of a variable, that's an indication you should be using a `dict` instead.

Comment: @chepner's comment is right on the mark. And in addition to that: if your functions and classes will only work correctly if they have access to these global variables (or rather the dict that holds them), they should be passed this data explicitly instead of assuming they're around and not accidentally shadowed or modified by some other code. Caring about the names of variables as data is *always* bad, globals are bad most of the time.